# Hurewicz Cofibration and extension of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

Let $A\to X$ be a Hurewicz fibration. The standard definition of it is through homotopy extension property, which simply says that for any $Y$, $f: A \to Y$ , $\tilde{f}:A\to Y$, $H: A\times I\to Y$ such that $\tilde{f}|_{A} = f$ and $H|_{A\times\{0\}}=f$ there exists $\tilde{H}: X\times I\to Y$ extending $H$, such that $\tilde{H}_{X\times\{0\}} = \tilde{f}$. However, it seems that the definition [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hurewicz+cofibration#:~:text=Definition,-Definition%202.1.&text=A%20Hurewicz%20cofibration%20i%3AA,the%20definition%20for%20pointed%20spaces) states that for a Hurewicz fibration, any map $f: A\to Y$ can be extended to a map $\tilde{f}:X\to Y$, such that $\tilde{f}|_{A} = f$.

Is this true? If not what are the correct conditions to be able to extend continuous maps from subsets?

Comment: That reference **does** mention the homotopy condition.

Comment: Of course, but it says this additional condition also. Is it true that it holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding, but in fact the definition in the linked nLab article is somewhat sloppy. The problem is the second bullet point. In order to give it an unambiguous meaning it should be replaced by

> for all continuous functions $f : A \to Y$ and all continuous functions $\tilde f: X \to Y$ such that $\tilde f \circ i = f$

Comment: Is there some well known condition on the pair $(X,A)$, such that there always exists such $\tilde{f}$?

Comment: @ArkadijBojko This is true for all $Y$ and all $f : A \to Y$ if and only if $A$ is a retract of $X$.